# build_app generates .ipa file that does not contain .app file

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, fastlane

Using fastlane the ipa file that is generated from build_app action contains no .app file. Compared to an old .ipa it has an executable instead of the .app file(unzipped)

[image]

because of this it is not possible to upload to testflight using fastlane. This is the error yielded:

```
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90167: "No .app bundles found in the package"
```

Trying to upload it through the application loader is no better. So in some way you could say that the Xcode compiler fails silently.

Can anybody give me some ideas as to what this error is caused by?